# GraphHopper and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, graphhopper

I store my geographical information in PostgreSQL database.

I want to use GraphHopper for my routing propose, but GraphHopper can read information in shapefiles or OSM format. 
I now convert my information to shapefile format and use GraphHopper.
But I want to read information directly from PostgreSQL and for this propose I have to write a custom reader for this.

How can write this reader?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" database works. Coding questions require code, but this "How can I write a custom reader" is so broad, I'm voting to close it as just *too broad*, since this is not a tutorial site.